# Changing Global Variables to Pointers

Tags: c

So I tried doing my monopoly code and I used a global variable because I'm not that good at using pointers. After analyzing my code and tried to see the next step. I saw that Global variables and structs are not allowed. So I'm trying to convert my code from using a global variable to using pointers since I think it is the only way. As you can see in my code, there is P1_CUR_AMT, P2_CUR_AMT, P1_CUR_POS, P2_CUR_POS and currentPlayer being used as a global variable. Here's my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

    int P1_CUR_AMT = 200; 
    int P2_CUR_AMT = 200; 

    int P1_CUR_POS = 0;
    int P2_CUR_POS = 0;

    int currentPlayer = 1;

int RollDice()
{
   return (rand() % 6) + 1;
}
int checkLand(int Money)
{
    int choice = 0;
    if(currentPlayer == 1)
    {
        P1_CUR_POS += RollDice();
        
        if(P1_CUR_POS == 10){
            P1_CUR_POS = 0;
        }
    else if(P1_CUR_POS > 10){
            P1_CUR_POS = P1_CUR_POS - 10;
        }
        choice = P1_CUR_POS;
    }
    if(currentPlayer == 2)
    {
        P2_CUR_POS += RollDice();
        if(P2_CUR_POS == 10){
            P2_CUR_POS = 0;
        }
    else if(P2_CUR_POS > 10)
        {
            P2_CUR_POS = P2_CUR_POS - 10;
        }
        choice = P2_CUR_POS;
    }

    char playerchoice;
    int dice = RollDice();

    if (choice == 0)
    {
        printf(" on Go.\n\n");
        Money += 200;
        printf("You collect $200 from the Bank.");
        printf("\nYour New Balance is $%d", Money);
    }

    else if (choice == 1)
    {
        printf(" on Tree House.\n\n");

        printf("\nWould you like to buy Tree House?");
        printf("\n\t [ y or Y ]\t[n or N]\n");
        scanf("%c", &playerchoice);
        scanf("%c", &playerchoice);

            if (playerchoice == 'y' || playerchoice == 'Y')
            {
                Money -= 20;
                printf("\nYou succesfully bought Tree House");
                printf("\nYour New Balance is $%d", Money);
            } 
            else if (playerchoice == 'n' || playerchoice == 'N')
                printf("Thank You for Staying.");

    }

    else if (choice == 2)
    {
            printf(" on Electric Company.\n\n");

            printf("\nWould you like to buy Electric Company?");
            printf("\n\t [ y or Y ]\t[n or N]\n");
            scanf("%c", &playerchoice);
            scanf("%c", &playerchoice);

            if (playerchoice == 'y' || playerchoice == 'Y')
            {
                Money -= 150;
                printf("\nYou succesfully bought Electric Company\n");
                printf("\nYour New Balance is $%d", Money);
            } 
            else if (playerchoice == 'n' || playerchoice == 'N')
                printf("Thank You for Staying.");

    }

    else if (choice == 3)
    {
        printf(" on Beach House.\n\n");

        printf("\nWould you like to buy Beach House?");
        printf("\n\t [ y or Y ]\t[n or N]\n");
        scanf("%c", &playerchoice);
        scanf("%c", &playerchoice);

        if (playerchoice == 'y' || playerchoice == 'Y')
        {
            Money -= 60;
            printf("\nYou succesfully bought Beach House");
            printf("\nYour New Balance is $%d", Money);
        } 

        else if (playerchoice == 'n' || playerchoice == 'N')
            printf("Thank You for Staying.");
    }

    else if (choice == 4) 
    {
        printf(" on Jail Time.\n\n");
        printf("You lose a turn.");
    }
    
    else if (choice == 5) 
    {
        printf(" on Castle.\n\n");

        printf("\nWould you like to buy Castle? ");
        printf("\n\t [ y or Y ]\t[n or N]\n");
        scanf("%c", &playerchoice);
        scanf("%c", &playerchoice);

            if (playerchoice == 'y' || playerchoice == 'Y')
            {
                Money -= 100;
                printf("\nYou succesfully bought Castle");
                printf("\nYour New Balance is $%d", Money);
            } 
            else if (playerchoice == 'n' || playerchoice == 'N') 
                printf("Thank You for Staying.");
    
    }

    else if (choice == 6)
    {
        printf(" on Feeling Lucky.\n\n");
        printf("Congratulations! You will roll the dice to determine your luck.\n");
        printf("You rolled %d", dice);
   // if (RollDice())
    }

    else if (choice == 7)
    {
    printf(" on Rail Road.\n\n");

    printf("Would you like to buy Rail Road?");
    printf("\n\t [ y or Y ]\t[n or N]\n");
    scanf("%c", &playerchoice);
    scanf("%c", &playerchoice);

        if (playerchoice == 'y' || playerchoice == 'Y')
        {
            Money -= 100;
            printf("\nYou succesfully bought Rail Road");
            printf("\nYour New Balance is $%d.", Money);
        } 
        else if (playerchoice == 'n' || playerchoice == 'N') 
            printf("Thank You for Staying.");

    }

    else if (choice == 8)
    {
    printf(" on Igloo.\n\n");

    printf("Would you like to buy Igloo?");
    printf("\n\t [ y or Y ]\t[n or N]\n");
    scanf("%c", &playerchoice);
    scanf("%c", &playerchoice);

        if (playerchoice == 'y' || playerchoice == 'Y')
        {
        Money -= 160;
        printf("\nYou succesfully bought Igloo");
        printf("\nYour New Balance is $%d.", Money);
        } 
        else if (playerchoice == 'n' || playerchoice == 'N') 
        printf("Thank You for Staying.");

    }

    else if (choice == 9)
    {
    printf(" on Farm House.\n\n");

    printf("Would you like to buy Farm House?");
    printf("\n\t [ y or Y ]\t[n or N]\n");
    scanf("%c", &playerchoice);
    scanf("%c", &playerchoice);

        if (playerchoice == 'y' || playerchoice == 'Y')
        {
            Money -= 180;
            printf("\nYou succesfully bought Farm House");
            printf("\nYour New Balance is $%d.", Money);
        } 
        else if (playerchoice == 'n' || playerchoice == 'N')
        printf("Thank You for Staying.");

    }
        
    return Money;
    
}


/*********************************************
FUNCTION TO RETURN GAME STATUS
1 FOR GAME IS OVER WITH PLAYER 2 WIN
2 FOR GAME IS OVER WITH PLAYER 1 WIN
3 FOR GAME IS IN PROGRESS
 **********************************************/
int checkWin()
{
    if(P1_CUR_AMT <= 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(P2_CUR_AMT <= 0)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        return 3;
    }
}
char PlayGame(char YesOrNo)
{
    printf("Would you like to play? Enter Y or N: ", YesOrNo);                                          
    scanf("%c", &YesOrNo);
    if (YesOrNo == 'Y' || YesOrNo == 'y')
    {
        Lines();
        printf("\n%40s", "Welcome To A Monopoly Game Called\n");
        printf("%30s", "Property Property\n\n");
        Lines();
        cRules();
        system ("cls");
        displayBoard();

    int player = 1, i;

        do
        {
            Lines();

            if(currentPlayer > 2) currentPlayer = 1;
            printf("It is Player %d turn.\n", currentPlayer);
            printf("Press any key to roll a dice.");
            getch();
            printf("\nPlayer %d landed", currentPlayer);

            if(currentPlayer == 1)
            {
              P1_CUR_AMT = checkLand(P1_CUR_AMT);
            }
            else
            {
              P2_CUR_AMT = checkLand(P2_CUR_AMT);
            }
            
            
            i = checkWin();
            currentPlayer++;
        }
        while (i != 1 || i != 2);
    }
}

int main()
{

    srand (time(0)); // Initialize random seed
    char choice;
    Introduction();
    getch();

    system ("cls");

    PlayGame(choice);
    getch();
    system ("cls");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: As you can see in my code I used a global variable, but the teacher doesn't allow us to use global variable and Im thinking of changing my global variable to pointers. But the problem is Im not that really familiar/good at using pointers. Can you teach me how to change my global variable to pointers? @Pablo

Comment: You say *I'm not that good at using pointers* but I think it really means *I don't understand pointers*. I suggest that you take your book/slides from the lecture and read again the chapter about pointers. That's the important thing here. Once you've understood that, you'll see what you have to do.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you delete the following global variables

```
int P1_CUR_AMT = 200; 
int P2_CUR_AMT = 200; 

int P1_CUR_POS = 0;
int P2_CUR_POS = 0;

int currentPlayer = 1;
```

and define the following `struct game_state` instead:

```
struct game_state
{
    int p1_cur_amt;
    int p2_cur_amt;

    int p1_cur_pos;
    int p2_cur_pos;

    int currentPlayer;
};
```

Now, in the function `PlayGame`, you can add the following line:

```
struct game_state gs = {
    .p1_cur_amt = 200,
    .p2_cur_amt = 200,
    .p1_cur_pos = 0,
    .p2_cur_pos = 0,
    .currentPlayer = 1
};
```

Now, your entire game state is no longer global. You can now pass a pointer to `gs` to all functions that require access to the game state. Of course, you will have to change the definitions of the parameter lists of these functions accordingly.

For example, you will probably have to change

```
int checkLand(int Money)
```

to:

```
int checkLand( struct game_state *pgs, int Money )
```

Now, for example when calling the function `checkLand` from `PlayGame`, instead of calling the function like this

```
P1_CUR_AMT = checkLand(P1_CUR_AMT);
```

you will have to call it like this:

```
gs.p1_cur_amt = checkLand( &gs, gs.p1_cur_amt );
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241325/discussion-on-answer-by-andreas-wenzel-changing-global-variables-to-pointers).